# How to handle result in SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, dialog

```
 public void SaveAs()
    {
        if(dataGridView1.ColumnCount>=2)
        {
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog.Filter = "Excel files (*.xls)|*.xls";
        saveFileDialog.FilterIndex = 0;
        saveFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
        saveFileDialog.CreatePrompt = true;
        saveFileDialog.Title = "Export Excel File To";
        saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();

        Stream myStream;

        myStream = saveFileDialog.OpenFile();
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(myStream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(-0));
        string str = "";
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    str += "\t";
                }
                str += dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText;
            }
            sw.WriteLine(str);
            for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                string tempStr = "";
                for (int k = 0; k < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
                {
                    if (k > 0)
                    {
                        tempStr += "\t";
                    }
                    tempStr += dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[k].Value.ToString();
                }
                sw.WriteLine(tempStr);
            }
            sw.Close();
            myStream.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          //  MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            sw.Close();
            myStream.Close();
        }

    }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("No data to save", "OK",
MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
    }
```

When I open the saving window and I decide not to save `DataGridView1` by clicking `Cancel` I have an error `Index was outside the bounds of the array.` at
    myStream = saveFileDialog.OpenFile();

I don't know what's wrong in here.

Answer (score 2):

Your culprit code is here:

```
saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();
Stream myStream;
myStream = saveFileDialog.OpenFile();
```

It should be like such:

```
if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {
    // code here for user pressing OK instead of the 'X' or 'Cancel'
    Stream myStream = saveFileDialog.OpenFile();
}
```

Without that check if you close the dialog (via the 'x') or press Cancel, your `saveFileDialog` has some "empty" values that you try and reference (which gives you the error).

Comment: How do I save the return value? I'm trying to cover multiple cases using else ifs without launching yet another different saveFileDialog.ShowDialog()?

Comment: @adamlogan you can do something like this: `System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();` .. then you can check what `result` is in a switch or if/else statement.

Answer (score 2):

The function [`ShowDialog()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e61ft40c(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a `DialogResult` to determine what action was taken. Just check the return value there before you continue. For example:

```
if(saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel) 
{
    //do something else here or just return
    return;
}
```